# Where do I find the official web location about what versions of Delphi are available?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Hello I would like to develop using delphi 7 programming language but I have some questions,

firstly is there a lot of different delphi languages e.g. Borland Delphi, Delphi 7, etc?

Second, is there any official web location providing resources about Delphi?

I would like to use borland delphi 7 studio but I can't find it under www.borland.com site, is it a commercial IDE?

Comment: Delphi is the tool, 7 is the version. If you must have version 7, you can find it on eBay.

Comment: You can get a new Delphi 7 license by just buying Delphi XE/XE2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to go to [www.embarcadero.com](http://www.embarcadero.com) as they purchased the IDE tools from [Borland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi).

The latest version of Delphi XE is available separately or as a part of RAD Studio XE (which also includes C++ builder, Delphi Prism, and Delphi PHP)

Comment: This is right.  Delphi 7 is no longer sold.  It hasn't been the current version of Delphi for almost 7 years now.  The current edition is Delphi XE, and it's got a lot of new features that make it easier to develop with.

Comment: technically, Embarcadero did not buy the tools from Borland. Borland created a separate company, CodeGear, to manage its developer tools so it could then focus on its enterprise and ALM tools, and then Embarcadero bought CodeGear later on, thus inheriting the developers tools as part of the acquisition.

Comment: Truly, Delphi 7 is no longer sold, but if you buy a Delphi XE License, embarcadero will give you away Delphi 7, Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2009, so, freely speaking, nowadays you can _buy_ a copy of Delphi 7 if you **buy** a copy of Delphi XE.

Comment: @Remy: That may be technically correct. However, CG was specifically created to manage developer tools and therefore the purchase of CG by Embarcadero was specifically the purchase of the developer tools, and since CG was a fully-owned subsidiary of Borland, Skamradt is right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Google being your friend in terms of finding official resources you can head off to www.delphibasics.co.uk to get a general introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a page for resources, note that you will also get my Delphi XE Starter Development Essentials PDF file as a free download once you install and register Delphi XE Starter Edition.

See also http://www.andreanolanusse.com/blogen/free-ebook-delphi-xe-starter-essentials-by-bob-swart/